# Text file manipulation with expressions and python

Tags: python, text

Since I'm not an expert in python or manipulating files (or anything else), 
I want to make a program that will turn this kind of txt file:

```
1:
2,5,1-2-12
356,4,8-9-2010
5651513531,3,5-6-2000
56,2,3-5-2000
2:
3,4,2-2-2002
8,4,2-2-2001
222222,5,2-2-01
222223,5,2-2-01
222210,5,2-2-01
222,5,2-2-01
```

...into this file:

```
1,2,5,1-2-12
1,356,4,8-9-2010
1,5651513531,3,5-6-2000
1,56,2,3-5-2000
2,3,4,2-2-2002
2,8,4,2-2-2001
2,222222,5,2-2-0
2,222223,5,2-2-01
2,222210,5,2-2-0
2,222,5,2-2-01
```

I have experimented with the following in python:

```
import re
with open ('/home/gmf/Desktop/split-combined/combined1.txt', 'r' ) as f: <br>
    content = f.read()
content_new = re.sub('(.*.):\n(.*.)\n', r'\1:\2\n\1:\n', content)


for x in range(100): <br>
    content_new = re.sub('(.*.):\n(.*.)\n', r'\1:\2\n\1:\n',  content_new)

file = open('new.txt', 'w')
file.write(content_new)

file.close()
```

But it returns a memory error

All i can think of is that  
a) i need to use a "while" loop instead of a "for" (but i know how to do so) and  
b) i need a terminating condition

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include the full error traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to make it easier is to use `fp.readlines()` which will read the file line-by-line until the end without needing a `while` loop. The same goes for `fp.writelines()`

```
import os

file = 'my_doc.txt'
new_file = 'new_doc.txt'

with open(file) as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()

start_line = None
new_lines = []
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.endswith(":"):
        start_line = line.strip(":")
        continue
    new_lines.append("{},{} {}".format(start_line, line, os.linesep))

with open(new_file, 'w') as fp:
    fp.writelines(new_lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following - in pseudo code:

```
   read the file for each line
      if line matches "number:"  (or: if line ends in ":")  then 
           $leadinvar=number_without_colon
      else
           $outputline = $number_without_colon + "," + $read_line


      write output file ($outputline)
```

Doing so will assume that the format corresponds to your example. You can set defaults of course if you don't have initial value.

I don't know enough python to give a working example, but I could do it in autoit3 easily.

Hope it's enough to help you to a working solution

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to see if the line contains a colon and you can still use a for loop just grab the first line before the loop as that should be the first number.

```
with open("combined1.txt", 'r') as f, open("new.txt", 'w') as o:
    num = next(f)[:-2]
    for line in f:
        if line.endswith(':\n'):
            num = line[:-2]
        else:
            o.write(f"{num},{line}")
```